# The controller with the name x is not registered

Tags: angularjs, controller

I can't figure out why i've this "controller is not registered" error in angular 1.6.4.

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller("formCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
});
```

**Index:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="js/formCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**App:**

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/:id", {
    templateUrl: './partials/main.html',
    controller: 'formCtrl'
  });
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're actually creating a new module for the controller, instead of reusing the existing app module.

To fix this you simply change your controller code to this:

```
angular.module('app').controller("formCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
});
```

You only need to specify the second argument of `angular.module()` when you intent to create a new module. If you want to register controllers, components, services, etc. for your application, you only apply the first argument: `angular.module('app')`.

Note, make sure your controller js file is loaded after the app js file.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
 app.controller("formCtrl",["$scope", "$rootScope", "$stateParams", function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
   $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
}]);
```